# Breaking long equation after a certain left bracket

Tags: equations, line-breaking, brackets

I am typing a long equation which needs to be broken just after the left bracket and three dots are placed at the end of the left bracket same line. Here is an example, in which, I need the third left bracket (i.e. of the column vector just before the plus sign) to be followed by three dots while aligning the rest of the equation in the newline with the equal sign.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{equation}\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    \dot{\omega}_m \\
    \dot{\theta}_m \\
    \dot{\omega}_v \\
    \dot{I}_m \\
  \end{array}
\right]
=
\left[
  \begin{array}{cccc}
    -\frac{C_m}{J_m} & -\frac{P_s K_s \psi}{2 \pi r_s^2 J_m} & 0 & \frac{K_{tm}}{J_m} \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & -\frac{P_s K_s \mu_p R_{mp}}{2 \pi r_s J_v} & -\frac{C_v}{J_v} & 0 \\
    -\frac{K_{em}}{L_m} & 0 & 0 & -\frac{R_m}{L_m} \\
  \end{array}
\right]
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    \omega_m \\
    \theta_m \\
    \omega_v \\
    I_m \\
  \end{array}
\right]
+
\left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
    0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 \\
    \frac{1}{J_v} & 0 \\
    0 & \frac{1}{L_m} \\
  \end{array}
\right]
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    F_v \\
    V_m(t) \\
  \end{array}
\right]
\end{equation}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's rather difficult to understand what you want, as there's no line break.

Comment: After the equal sign, there is a left bracket which I need the break occurs after and three dots are placed to indicate a line break.

Comment: Sorry, but one has to know better the context: are you using an aligning display math environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not at all clear what you want to do; I would split the equation in this way

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \dot{\omega}_m \\
    \dot{\theta}_m \\
    \dot{\omega}_v \\
    \dot{I}_m \\
  \end{bmatrix}
&=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    -\frac{C_m}{J_m} & -\frac{P_s K_s \psi}{2 \pi r_s^2 J_m} & 0 & \frac{K_{tm}}{J_m} \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & -\frac{P_s K_s \mu_p R_{mp}}{2 \pi r_s J_v} & -\frac{C_v}{J_v} & 0 \\
    -\frac{K_{em}}{L_m} & 0 & 0 & -\frac{R_m}{L_m} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \omega_m \\
    \theta_m \\
    \omega_v \\
    I_m \\
  \end{bmatrix}
\\
&\qquad+
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 \\
    \frac{1}{J_v} & 0 \\
    0 & \frac{1}{L_m} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    F_v \\
    V_m(t) \\
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The `center` environment is out of place; the `bmatrix` environment gives better matrices than `\left[\begin{array}{..}...\end{array}\right]`.

---

[image]

---

With a reduced column width one can try and squeeze the matrix columns and break at the product. Here's an example at a column width of 229.5pt (3.2 inches or 8 centimeters):

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{equation}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{1pt}
\begin{aligned}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \dot{\omega}_m \\
    \dot{\theta}_m \\
    \dot{\omega}_v \\
    \dot{I}_m \\
  \end{bmatrix}
&=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    -\frac{C_m}{J_m} & -\frac{P_s K_s \psi}{2 \pi r_s^2 J_m} & 0 & \frac{K_{tm}}{J_m} \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & -\frac{P_s K_s \mu_p R_{mp}}{2 \pi r_s J_v} & -\frac{C_v}{J_v} & 0 \\
    -\frac{K_{em}}{L_m} & 0 & 0 & -\frac{R_m}{L_m} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
\\
&\qquad\cdot
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \omega_m \\
    \theta_m \\
    \omega_v \\
    I_m \\
  \end{bmatrix}
+
  \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 \\
    \frac{1}{J_v} & 0 \\
    0 & \frac{1}{L_m} \\
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    F_v \\
    V_m(t) \\
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Sorry for not being clear and grateful for your help. how about making the break just after the left bracket of the rightmost column vector in your answer preview ?

Comment: @Diaa But do you really want to split *after* a left bracket?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am talking about, since I want to type this equation in two-column article format and I don't know where to break the equation to fit the desired format.

Comment: Can you tell the column width? Breaking after a left bracket would be the very last resort.

Comment: From Elsevier guide, it states the width will be 224pt in the two-columns format

Comment: @Diaa The standard article width is 229.5pt, so my second example should fit.

Comment: Your example really fits, and I am very sorry for my confusion and highly grateful for your patience and help.

I've learnt so much.

Thanks

Comment: The compilation process is taking a long time!

Answer (score 5):

It wasn't very clear exactly what alignment you meant, but for any kind of math alignment it is usually best to use the `amsmath` package. I *think* you meant this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\arrayb{
  \begin{array}{c}
    \omega_m \\
    \theta_m \\
    \omega_v \\
    I_m 
  \end{array}}

\begin{align}
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    \dot{\omega}_m \\
    \dot{\theta}_m \\
    \dot{\omega}_v \\
    \dot{I}_m 
  \end{array}
\right]
&=
\left[
  \begin{array}{cccc}
    -\frac{C_m}{J_m} & -\frac{P_s K_s \psi}{2 \pi r_s^2 J_m} & 0 & \frac{K_{tm}}{J_m} \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & -\frac{P_s K_s \mu_p R_{mp}}{2 \pi r_s J_v} & -\frac{C_v}{J_v} & 0 \\
    -\frac{K_{em}}{L_m} & 0 & 0 & -\frac{R_m}{L_m}
  \end{array}
\right]
\left[\vphantom{\arrayb}\right.\cdots
\\\notag
&
\left.\arrayb\right]
+
\left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
    0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 \\
    \frac{1}{J_v} & 0 \\
    0 & \frac{1}{L_m}
  \end{array}
\right]
\left[
  \begin{array}{c}
    F_v \\
    V_m(t)
  \end{array}
\right]
\end{align}


\end{document}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, but when I tried to apply this for my equation an error was generated saying wrong nesting of equation structure. So, I dont know what to do. Kindly, could you tell me whether to paste my original equation in the comment or edit my original post ?

Comment: Sorry for my confusion, but do you mean that I edit my original post ?

Comment: I am really grateful for your patience. I've edited the question to my original equation.

Comment: I deleted some of the earlier comments as no longer relevant (you may do same:-) and updated the answer based on your new example